# Why does it say that my phone isn't rooted properly?

Tags: root-access, 5.1-lollipop

#### Question:

Why does it say that my phone isn't rooted properly? Also, can it get bricked?

#### Full story:

I got some malware, which my antivirus couldn't detect, so I installed an app called "Stubborn Trojan Killer" from the google play store. It told me that in order to stop the malware I had to root my phone and gave me instructions.

In the instructions it included two root programs, one is "KingRoot" and the second one is "KingoRoot". I tried the second one first, but it didn't work, so then I tried the first one and it did, but the other antivirus programs I installed kept labeling it as a virus, plus I read somewhere that the program itself is shady, so I decided to uninstall it.

So getting to the point, I read somewhere that rooting your device can get it "bricked" (would be great if someone can explain how you ACTUALLY brick your phone), so I got paranoid and downloaded an app called "Root Checker" It checked if I had root access, but it didn't give me a clear yes or no, it just said that it isn't installed properly and now I'm paranoid that it could get bricked or something.

How do I fix this? I'm really new to rooting and all of that so I would appreciate some help.

My phone's name is Allview Soul Style, and it runs Android 5.1.

Comment: To Firelord: Yes my android model is 5.1 and my phone's name is Allview Soul Style. I don't understand what you mean, I just rooted my phone and the other antivirus programs showed that It's malware, so when I uninstalled KingRoot it stopped and said that it's fixed. I'm just paranoid because it says that my root isn't rooted properly, although it did when I hadn't uninstalled KingRoot if I may add. I checked if It's rooted from "Root Checker", and it said that it isn't working properly, so I'm paranoid that it might get bricked, even though I'm not sure how bricking really works.

Comment: If your device were [bricked](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/unbricking/info), it would be working [like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WAL8V.png) – but not boot up, able to start apps, and telling you it's not rooted properly. From the reports we get here, I'd keep my fingers off Kingoroot – but that's too late for you now. If you want to be absolutely safe, you could [flash a clean ROM](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rom-flashing/info).

Comment: I was talking about KingRoot and not KingoRoot, KingoRoot didn't appear as malware. Anyway, the malware got away when I uninstalled KingRoot, so I don't want to be too impulsive. Yes I know that my phone isn't bricked but, I'm paranoid that it might get bricked because it says that the root didn't root properly.

Comment: Sorry for messing up the two – I'll never keep them apart :) As I wrote, against paranoia there's flashing a clean ROM :)

Comment: What about what the program said? Is it a problem that it says that the root hasn't been installed properly?

Comment: Parts of it have been removed by uninstalling it I guess. Cannot say, never used it myself.